# Understanding the creation of custom UITableCellView - loading from Nibs in MonoTouch

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, nib

I've used this tutorial several times: http://www.alexyork.net/blog/2011/07/18/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-with-monotouch-the-correct-way/

But there's a section of code in it that I don't understand well:

```
    cell = new MyCustomCell();
    var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("MyCustomCell", cell, null);
    cell = Runtime.GetNSObject( views.ValueAt(0) ) as MyCustomCell;
```

I have tried to remove this - to place the LoadNib inside the constructors - but this has gone wrong with the outlets just not getting wired up correctly.

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here? Why can't I just load this Nib file within the constructors? Why is it necessary for two cell instances to actually be created? What is actually happening in the background? Can the code be improved?

Interested to learn about this as I do it quite often and I'd love to make the process cleaner

Stuart

If it helps, an example cell is: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCrossConference/blob/master/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Touch/Cells/SessionCell2.cs

Comment: I tried to write a complete answer, but I am still not able to. There's a lot of stuff about it. In short: you do not need outlets from your cell connected to your File's Owner in the NIB and the owner you pass to LoadNib(..), should have outlets declared. I am currently writing an article on NIB loading which I believe explains a lot. Until then, check the sample project I have created: http://github.com/dtavlikos/JTNibManager

Comment: Thanks. Wlooking forward to the blog post and to learning. I would love to you the sib editor more but currently I find the whole process a bit confusing (and maybe buggy too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at things one at a time.

The LoadNib method unarchives (and instantiates) the contents of a NIB. The first parameter is the name of the NIB and the second parameter is the owner of the NIB that will be loaded. That is, the NIB's "File's Owner" Placeholder object which, in this case, I suppose it is just an NSObject.

The LoadNib method also returns an NSArray of objects. These objects are the Top-Level objects of the NIB which, in this case, is the custom cell you created in the NIB.

I suppose when you move the above code in the constructor, you implement something like this:

```
public MyCustomCell() : base()
{
    NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("MyCustomCell", this, null);
}
```

If you don't, and your implementation is different but you are still using LoadNib in the constructor, the outlets will still fail to be retained. They are created all right, but they are not retained. It is not the MonoTouch GC that kicks in or anything, it is the native outlet that is being autoreleased. You might wonder "but why can I use LoadNib in the constructor of a UIViewController and still get my outlets?". That is correct, you can use the LoadNib in the constructor of a UIViewController but there is one important difference: that UIViewController is your File's Owner Placeholder object. If you tried to do the same with a controller that is not the File's Owner, you'd get the same failure in retaining the outlets.

What you basically need from the LoadNib method, is the return array of Top-Level objects. So, to make it work in the constructor, the "correct" way would be:

```
    public MyCustomCell() : base()
    {
        NSArray arr = NSBundle.LoadNib("MyCustomCell", this, null);
        this = Runtime.GetNSObject(arr.ValueAt(0)); // should retain everything,
        //BUT: Compile error!
    }
```

which basically is the same thing you are doing to load the NIB outside of the constructor. But of course, we cannot do "this = something". So, to sum up with the LoadNib creation: your "MyCustomCell" is a Top-Level object and it is provided to us through the return value of the LoadNib and not by passing it as an owner.

The next thing you correctly noticed is about the two instances: I believe that is also wrong. Take a look at your code above, with some comments:

```
 cell = new MyCustomCell(); // Created a new instance of MyCustomCell
 var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("MyCustomCell", cell, null); // Assigned it as an owner
 cell = Runtime.GetNSObject( views.ValueAt(0) ) as MyCustomCell; // What happens to the owner?
```

I think that is a memory leak. Consider the following though:

```
// Not needed
//cell = new MyCustomCell(); 
var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("MyCustomCell", tableView, null); // Owner is now the tableView
cell = Runtime.GetNSObject( views.ValueAt(0) ) as MyCustomCell;
views = null; // Don't need it anymore
```

The owner of the NIB is now the table view. The table view will be handled by the runtime (in most cases at least).

If you still want to use LoadNib inside your MyCustomCell class to create an instance, just create a static method:

```
// Inside MyCustomCell
public static MyCustomCell CreateCell(NSObject owner)
{
    NSArray topLevelObjects = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("MyCustomCell", owner, null);
    MyCustomCell customCell = Runtime.GetNSObject(topLevelObjects.ValueAt(0)) as MyCustomCell;
    topLevelObjects = null;
    return customCell;
}
```

For more info on NIB loading:

[Can you NIB it?](http://software.tavlikos.com/2012/03/27/can-you-nib-it/)

[Apple's Resource Programming Guide on NIB files](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Dimitri, great answer, just had a comment.  I'm not sure setting `views = null` or `topLevelObjects = null` does anything helpful.  If they are local variables you don't have to set them to null--they will get GC'ed no problem.  I love your 'Can you NIB it?' article, been wondering the internals of that stuff myself.

Comment: Hi Jonathan. You are right, it's just that I've been reading way to many ObjC stuff lately. As far as NIB loading, I am preparing more stuff, stay tuned... ;)

Comment: Yeah, I've worked in C# so long, I take it for granted.  I'm not sure I'd make it in the Obj-C world.